# Save superscript symbols in SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, windows, superscript

I want to save alpha, beta, theta and all super script symbols in SQL Server database through my .Net windows application. And I need to fetch again and want to show on label control. What do I have to do? I am using C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store them in a nchar(n) or nvarchar(n) field in sql server. Don't forget the N' ' notation for strings. To represent the characters in you label, you'll need a unicode font.

I think everything else is the same for storing, retrieving and placing string values on a label.

Comment: No, I tried this, but when i am going to store theta, it stores It as "T". so everything is not same. also when i am going to retrieve it , i get "T". so i found the remedy here. convert it in to Byte encoding and then save it. again pick it as byte and deencode it in to char and then represent. this is working perfect as of now.